# Output From XDocument To .CSV File in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the output from an XDocument the way I would like it into a .CSV File.  I was wondering if anyone could help me?

First, here's the XML:

```
<Main>
  <Node1>
    <Node1a>1</Node1a>
    <Node1b>2</Node1b>
  </Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node2a>Three</Node2a>
    <Node2b>Four</Node2b>
  </Node2>
</Main>
```

I'm able to convert this XML document to a string (i.e.: called sString below) and pass it into my VB.NET function.  I currently have...

```
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(sString)
    Dim myOutput As New StringBuilder(1000)

    For Each node As XElement In doc.Descendants("Main")
        For Each innerNode As XElement In node.Elements()
            myOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Attribute("Node1a").Value)
            myOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", "!")
            myOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Attribute("Node1b").Value)
            myOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", "!")
            myOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Attribute("Node2a").Value)
            myOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", "!")
            myOutput.AppendFormat("{0},", innerNode.Attribute("Node2b").Value)
        Next

        myOutput.AppendLine()
    Next

    Dim finalCSVstring as string
    finalCSVstring = myOutput.ToString()
```

This works "kinda"...but I think I'm getting messed up on the inner loop of nodes and writing out those values.

What I would like is the final output to look like:

```
1|2|Three|Four
```

Where a "|" separates the various values.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `String.Join` on the leaf elements e.g.

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("../../XMLFile1.xml")
Dim s As String = String.Join("|", doc.Descendants().Where(Function(d) Not (d.HasElements)).Select(Function(e) e.Value))
Console.WriteLine(s)
```

outputs `1|2|Three|Four`. I have used `XDocument.Load` to parse the XML from an input file, of course if you have a string use `XDocument.Parse`.

In your sample the main error is using `innerNode.Attribute` as there are no attributes in the input sample. So using `innerNode.Element` instead would do. But there is no need to write loops.